# Registering one click event for multiple buttons and passing a different value per button

Tags: c#, winforms, button, procedural-generation

I procedurally generate buttons based on what is in a list, this list contains file paths. I need each button to open the specific file from the path using: 
`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filePath)`

However, the `button.Click =` requires the function it runs to be `System.EventHandler`whereas the code to open the file is a `System.Diagnostics.Process`.

Below is the code which generates the buttons:

```
 private int importButtonFactory()
    {
        int numberOfButtons = 0;

        int top = 70;
        int left = 100;

        foreach (Import import in ImportList)
        {
            Button button = new Button();
            button.Left = left;
            button.Top = top;
            this.Controls.Add(button);
            top += button.Height + 2;
            numberOfButtons++;
            button.Text = import.Scheme;
            button.Click += openFile_Click(import.Path);
        }

        return numberOfButtons;
    }
```

The function for `button.Click` "openFile_Click()":

```
        private void openFile_Click(string filePath)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filePath);
        }
```

This is what I initially thought would simply work, but but function in the previous function complains with error: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.EventHandler'" If I make the function of that type to try and please it says the function doesn't return any values.... which I don't want it do, but `System.EventHandler` seems to need it to.

I'm not sure if there is any dummy data I can have it return as `System.EventHandler` just to shut it up, or of there is a proper way I don't know of to get my scenario to work.

Edit: This is a Windows Form Application

Comment: `System.EventHandler` has its signature.

Comment: Is it asp.net or winform application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your event handler must match the event signature. So your button click handler *must* use this signature:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Now to identify which URL belongs to which button, you can give the button a Tag, for example holding the list index, assuming it is a `List<T>` or another indexable collection:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < ImportList.Count; i++)
    {
        // ...
        button.Text = ImportList[i].Scheme;
        button.Tag = i;
        button.Click += Button_Click;
    }
```

Then in your click handler:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Button button = sender as Button;
    int index = (int)button.Tag;

    var import = ImportList[index];

    Process.Start(import.Path); 
}
```

Comment: If it's ASP.NET then the value can also be passed as button's `CommandArgument` ... for information.

Comment: Beautiful, this makes sense and works great, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [lambda expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) to do something like this:

```
button.Click += (object sndr, EventArgs c_args) => openFile_Click(import.Path);
```

This code works. However, the compiler will give you a warning that you are accessing the `foreach` loop variable (`import`) in closure. To fix this, create a local variable like this:

```
var path = import.Path;

button.Click += (object sndr, EventArgs c_args) => openFile_Click(path);
```

Comment: @HamletHakobyan, lambda expressions were added with .NET version 3.5. It is probably safe to assume that OP is using a version that has lambda expressions.

Comment: I suggest you to try the code and try to understand what is the problem.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan, I tested it with .NET 3.5 and it is working. Can you please explain why you think it will not work?

Comment: You have tested whole `foreach` loop or just one event handler?

Comment: I tested the whole `foreach` loop

Comment: And for each button it opens different files or the same?

Comment: It runs `openFile_Click` passing different argument for each button. Are you worried about capturing the loop variable?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I wrote `.NET 4.0` instead of `C# 4.0`.

Comment: This method works wonderfully for me with no issues so far using my existing foreach loop, thanks.